# SSRS View Report: Change View Report Button Text

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

Is there anyway to change the View Report Button in SSRS to say something else. Such as "Hello", or "See Data". Is there a place in the SSRS XML RDL, I can edit?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify the button text through javascript if you edit `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\Reporting Services\ReportManager\js\ReportingServices.js`

See this [blog post](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/reporting-services-add-a-logo-to-the-report-manager)

Just define a function using the DOM to replace the button text and add it to the `addLoadEvent`

Comment: This file does not exist in SSRS2016